# Vmware Wayland enabling 1920x1080 resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, vmware, monitor, wayland

There already are many of the same questions but they ALL seems to be about the default X11, because they are all using "Virtual1", which seems to be the monitor name in X11, which is different from "XWAYLAND0", which seems to be the default monitor name for Wayland.

I have tried methods like

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "XWAYLAND0"
    Modeline "p1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "p1920x1080"
EndSection
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video=XWAYLAND0:1920x1080@60"
```

or

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND01920x1080
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0--mode 1920x1080
```

But none of them worked for Wayland. The top one worked for X11, though. So, is there any way to get 1080p on "Ubuntu (Wayland)", or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is skipping the monitor name.

In `/etc/default/grub` file,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video=1920x1080-32"
```

Also setting below variables helps

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_TERMINAL=gfxterm
```

Then run command

```
sudo update-grub
```

For more info: https://www.systutorials.com/configuration-of-linux-kernel-video-mode/